# Cloning an array instanced in a class

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems to understand why I cant clone an array of a class. The array is created and filled properly, all I need its to create a new array with the same values inside but I can't.

I do the following:

```
class ArrayExcercise{
    constructor(size){
        this.array = new Array(size);
    }
    randomNumber(){
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    }
    fillArray(){
        for(let i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++){
            this.array[i] = this.randomNumber();
        }
    }
}

const newArray = new ArrayExcercise(3);
newArray.fillArray();
const cloneArray = [...newArray];
console.log(cloneArray);
```

And all I get from that is

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

Comment: maybe `const cloneArray = [...newArray.array];` ? `newArray` is not the array itself, it is the class, so it is not iterable, the array is the property that is inside, called `array`

Answer (score 1):

That's because `newArray` is your actual class. Your iterable object is a property of your class called `array`. You should be going after `ArrayExercise.array` / `newArray.array` instead of just `newArray`

```js
class ArrayExcercise{
    constructor(size){
        this.array = new Array(size);
    }
    randomNumber(){
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    }
    fillArray(){
        for(let i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++){
            this.array[i] = this.randomNumber();
        }
    }
}

const newArray = new ArrayExcercise(3);
newArray.fillArray();
const cloneArray = [...newArray.array]; // <-- newArray.array is what you want
console.log(cloneArray);
```

Comment: I was writing my answer based on my comment, exaclty like this, hahaha +1